# Laravel using Mutator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, controller, mutators

I am using Mutator to change the Attribute `Name` in the Model. So far i used to concatinate the value with `'1'` But i want to concatinate with another value named `$Subname` and i should get back in the controller before i use `DataModel::create($Data);`

**Code i have already**

```
public function setNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['Name'] = $Name.'1';
}
```

**Code i need to change**

```
public function setNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['Name'] = $Name.$SubName;
}
```

So How can i use the two attribute inside the function and get back in the Controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$Name` or `$SubName` because they won't be defined. What you want here is probably:

```
public function setNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['Name'] = $value.$this->SubName;
}
```

Comment: And at the same time can i do  `$this->attributes['Name'] = $value.$this->SubName;` and  `$this->attributes['AnotherName'] = $value.$this->SubNameAnother;` In Same Function ? (I tried and it failed)